# Image is not responsive according to parent div background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a banner/hero section where a parent div is containing an image as background image and inside that parent div there is another image.

The problem is that the child div is not getting responsive.

```
<div class="full_width">
    <div class="banner-box">
        <img src="https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/03/18/banner-right-image30d6a.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the original banner which I exported from psd.

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/03/18/banner-ori.jpg

And the demo(full screen) is here https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/61df2zj8/embedded/result/

Normal -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/61df2zj8/

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What does `not getting responsive mean"?

Comment: if you resize the browser on full screen demo then the image is not resizing according to parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-width` on image like `max-width: 80%`

Comment: I did and the image is resizing on browser resize which is good but at the other hand it is not properly scaled with the background image so there is a space left at the bottom on resize.

Answer (score 0):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/61df2zj8/2/)**

Give `width:100%` for the img.

```
.banner-box > img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -66px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I did but not working properly.If you see the original banner image then the food image at the right hand side is properly scaled with the background image on browser resize.